# Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi, can't enter BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop (HP b119es), but it kept booting into Windows (it has a hard-coded EFI). So, I used the Boot-Repair tool to rename EFI files - the result is this:

```
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi : Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

The problem is that I now can't enter BIOS or boot from USB, this error keeps occurring. I thought about booting a live Ubuntu USB; but, I can't access the boot menu <kbd>F9</kbd> or BIOS <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Did I corrupt the BIOS? What should I do?

Comment: Accessing BIOS or UEFI (your case) is independent of the installed OSes. Try ESC immediately after powering on (or F10 if you're sure) and SPAM the key. Furthermore, I've heard about the workaround you tried to implement - never had to use it though - and I'm almost sure it isn't the way you did.

Comment: You should not have grubx64.efi in Microsofts folder anyway. So not sure what is asking for that. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: As mentioned, you shouldnt have been able to break your Bios with the Ubuntu installer. Unless you are leaving something out, it should 100% still be there. Did you try something else that you arent mentioning? Also, I googled around, but couldnt find an explanation for a hard coded EFI. Could you please explain that a little more because I think your understanding of UEFI may be part of the issue.

Comment: @jwcooper Years ago I remember reading something about a few laptops that had a UEFI implementation that didn't conform with what the official standards should be. Those booted Windows no matter what you did. I also remember discussions about a workaround that involved renaming EFI files so what the OP describes is smehow plausible but again, the implementation was probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your system is not completely shutting off when you are trying to restart. Make sure the machine is powered down completely (pull out the battery if necessary) and then attempt to get into the bios again. It may be tricky but is accessible.

I would rename the files back to the old names and then add a boot option inside of the bios once you are in. If you want to use grub then you have to add the boot option for it by clicking "add boot option" inside of the bios, selecting the drive/partition that grub is on, and then navigate to the grubx64.efi file. This should all be done in the bios and not by renaming the files on the disk.